# Resizing an image within an <a> tag

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, image-resizing

Currently I'm just trying to have an image scale down depending on the window size of the browser. The image is held within an anchor link, so that if you click on it it sends you to the home page.

My problem right now is that when it's resized, the only part of the image that connects to the anchor is a small portion of the bottom, or if I resize it to be smaller, all ability to click on it disappears.

Thoughts? Solutions?

I REALLY don't want to make an image map and scale it dynamically with javascript.

HTML:

```
<a href="Index.html" id="leftNav">
    <img class="bar" id="leftBar" src="./files/images/Nav First.png" border="0" />
</a>
<img class="bar" id="midBar" src="./files/images/Nav Select.png" border="0" />
<a href="#" onClick="goToLastComic(); return false;" id="rightNav">
    <img class="bar" id="rightBar" src="./files/images/Nav Last.png" border="0" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
    .bar{
    display:inline-block;
}
#leftBar, #leftNav{
width:15%;
height:auto;
max-height: 83px;
}
#midBar{
width:55%;
height:auto;
max-height: 83px;
}
#rightBar, #rightNav{
width:15%;
height:auto;
max-height: 83px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the anchor the attribute display: block? That should do. Also you need to give to the anchor width, height and max-height that you have set up in #leftbar so far.

Comment: Unfortunately that skews my nav bar up- It's horizontal with three of these images inline.

Comment: Make the elements in your nav bar floating elements, not inline

Comment: you could make them `inline-block` (or float as ADASein suggested) to get them side by side and still have height and width.

Comment: Set them to float:left and float:right, did not fix the clicking areas. Currently they are inline-block

Answer (score -1):

I found my problem- I had a form with absolute positioning that was getting in the way. I don't know why I set the form dimensions as I did, but it was a stupid fix. The width threw me off- 100% and 83px height, which is what I did to center the form before I knew about auto margins.